# Why doesn't this this line appear between tables?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to learn how to typeset caption tables but...
why doesn't this text appear between tables?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}
\caption{A subtable}\label{tab:1a}
\end{subtable}%
%
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Another subtable}\label{tab:1b}
\end{subtable}
\caption{A table}\label{tab:1}
\end{table}

 Why is not this text between the tables?


\begin{table}
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}
\caption{A subtable}\label{tab:1a}
\end{subtable}%
%
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
{\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Another subtable}\label{tab:1b}
\end{subtable}
\caption{A table}\label{tab:1}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

Comment: Use `\begin{table}[htb]` for both tables.

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not need a `table` environment to make a table, you can just use `tabular` directly (just as you do not need `figure` to include an image, that is done with `\includegraphicics`)

The only point of `figure` and `table` is that they are *floats* which means that they can be moved by the system to help with page breaking. In the comments it has been suggested to include `h` in the float position arguments which gives the possibility of the float being placed "here" and not being moved, but even if it happens not to move you should not write the surrounding text assuming that as any edit to the document can change the page breaking decisions.

That is why you should put a referencable caption in a floating environment and refer to it by reference without assuming it is typeset in place.

Comment: thank you very much. Yesterday i understood but today I´m trying and have aline at the final .tex that don´t appear where I want, and I can´t understand. Could you tell me why?. Is a little large to post directly here, so... https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxsidpz23ipmfbg/place.zip

Comment: @MikaIke sorry not fetching zip files:-) try to make a small example of the problem and ask a new question.